# Is HTTP Strict Transport Security needed when only listening on port 443?

Tags: hsts

Is HSTS needed on a server that listens only on 443 port? If a MITM attack is carried out, the server won't respond on HTTP.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't matter what your server does. For all we care it could even be down, and MITM attacks would still be possible. All it matters is what the **client** does. If your client makes insecure requests or accepts untrusted responses, then a MITM becomes possible. HSTS is used to make sure that your client only uses HTTPS to connect to your server, which means it will always use secure requests and accept trusted responses.

Imagine visiting the following malicious HTML page:

```
<img src="http://www.your-server.com/foo">
```

Without HSTS, your browser will send an HTTP request which can be intercepted by the MITM, who could steal the authentication data that is automatically sent in that request (cookies, headers, etc.)
With HSTS, provided that your website is already in the list of domains that have HSTS, your browser will refuse to make that request in plain HTTP, and the MITM won't be able see the content of the request or try to impersonate your server.

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely use Strict Transport Security even if you are not serving HTTP.

HSTS is about more than requiring HTTPS when HTTP is also served (though that's a good reason by itself as it can rewrite insecure URLs if they were forgotten).

It is also used to tell a browser that the content should be over TLS. This can help to defeat SSL-stripping man-in-the-middle attacks where a "proxy" is serving the target website in plain HTTP.

If you are visiting the same website frequently, you browser will remember the HSTS policy for at most `max-age`. Should someone attempt a MITM between visits, you browser will notice and refuse to connect.

If you have not visited the website recently, it may be in a preloaded HSTS list.

You can find more info about the basics on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) and more details in [RFC 6797](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797).